# syncfusion dynamic grid data with multiple response with angular7

Tags: angular7, syncfusion

I am trying to create a grid with syncfusion but I have to go for two API calls and I have to add response from both API response and then populate data using syncfusion with angular7. Not able to do so.

Please help me with a jsfiddle or any working sample.

I have used :

```
npm install @syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids --save 

npm install @syncfusion/ej2 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the API response to the grid by updating the Grid DataSource.Please refer to the below sample for binding grid data with two API calls in Angular7 and we have used **Ajax** in **created** event to achieve your requirement.

[html]

```
<ejs-grid [dataSource]='data' (created)='created($event)' height='350'>
    <e-columns>
        <e-column field='OrderID' headerText='Order ID' width='120' textAlign='Right'></e-column>
        <e-column field='CustomerID' headerText='Customer Name' width='150'></e-column>
        <e-column field='ShipCity' headerText='Ship Country' width='150'></e-column>
    </e-columns>
</ejs-grid>
```

[ts]

```
created(args){
let ajax = new Ajax();
ajax.type = 'Get';
ajax.url = 'https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/Orders';
ajax.send();
ajax.onSuccess = (args) => {
  this.data = JSON.parse(args);
};
let ajax2 = new Ajax();
ajax2.type = 'Get';
ajax2.url = 'https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/Orders';
ajax2.send();
ajax2.onSuccess = (args) => {
  this.data = [...this.data , ...JSON.parse(args)];
}
```

Refer the below sample and documentation for more information,

[Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-z1hpfy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Documentation: [Created](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/grid/#created), [Ajax](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/base/ajax/)